# Angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.4) Login/admin router template pathing

Tags: angularjs, angular

Good day to you all. Hopefully a quick question. =)

I have a login page with the route setup as /login

I also have other routes/pages set up e.g. /dashboard, /history, /sales and those pages all share a sidebar navigation.

The ploblem i am having is that i need the login page to not show the sidebar and only show the form. Once logged in i need to show the sidebar and have the right side of the page change to the content of the requested url.

for my routes i am using

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard.component';
import { HistoryComponent } from './components/pages/history.component';
import { SalesComponent } from './components/pages/sales.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/pages/login.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  { path: 'history', component: HistoryComponent },
  { path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }

];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

for my app.ts

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: You won't solve this with router configuration alone.  You should create a login service that tracks whether or not the user is currently logged in.  You can then use this login service in your app compoonent (or whatever top level component) to show/hide your sidebar with `*ngIf` (or whatever mechanism).

Comment: gotcha, didnt know if there was any inheritance templating options.. Thanks!